# Token Error: EOF in multiline statement in Python... what does this mean?

Tags: python, token, eof

I am just starting to learn how to code and I am learning with Python. I am trying to write a program that will print an ASCII art every time a user types 1, but when I try to run the module it gives me the error in the title.

here is my code:
Where did I go wrong?

```
yORn = int(input("Type 1 to run the program, Type 2 to Exit:  ")
while yORn = 1:
   Name = str(input("What is your name?"))
   print("      1111111111111111111111     ")
   print("      1                    1     ")
   print("      1                    1     ")
   print("      1   Hello...         1     ")
   print("      1        ", Name,"   1     ")
   print("      1                    1     ")
   print("      1                    1     ")
   print("      1111111111111111111111___  ")
   print("             11111111          | ")
   print("     ------------------------- O ")
   print("    1.............._... ... 1    ")
   print("   1...................... 1     ")
   print("  -------------------------      ")
   yORn = int(input("Type 1 to run the program, Type 2 to Exit:  ")
print ("GoodBye")
```

Answer (score 10):

You've got the immediate answer (the missing parentheses), but if you're doing stuff like this, I would suggest another approach, and use multi-line strings using (using triple quoted strings), and string formatting:

```
ascii_art = """
    1111111111111111111111     
    1                    1     
    1                    1     
    1   Hello...         1     
    1{name:^20}1     
    1                    1     
    1                    1     
    1111111111111111111111___  
           11111111          | 
   ------------------------- O 
   .............._... ... 1    
 1...................... 1     
-------------------------          
"""

print ascii_art.format(name='Kevin')
```

The `{name:^20}` takes the parameter `name` and centrally aligns it within 20 characters `^20` so it fits nicely within the block (a computer monitor?)....

Example output:

```
    1111111111111111111111     
    1                    1     
    1                    1     
    1   Hello...         1     
    1       Kevin        1     
    1                    1     
    1                    1     
    1111111111111111111111___  
           11111111          | 
   ------------------------- O 
   .............._... ... 1    
 1...................... 1     
-------------------------
```

Answer (score 6):

You forgot to close the parenthesis in two places:

```
yORn = int(input("Type 1 to run the program, Type 2 to Exit:  ")) # < 2 closing parenthesis here
```

And again at the end of your code.

Note that your `while` statement also has an error; `=` is assignment, you meant `==` instead:

```
while yORn == 1:
```

Comment: thank you! now I'm trying to get the variable Name to show up on the computer but it apparently does not like the way I'm telling it to do it.

Comment: @KevinDowling: It works perfectly fine if your name happens to be 7 characters long, like my first name.. ;-) Jon is showing you a way to deal with that part.

Comment: @KevinDowling I think apart from `str(input(...` where `str` is redundant, with what Martijn's pointed out, and using string formatting as I suggest in my answer - you should be covered :)